# Dynamically add to JS Object with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I have a Object to dynamically fill my DropDown list.

```
var myOptions = [
                   { name: Projekte[1][1], value: "val1" },
                   { name: Projekte[2][1], value: "val2" },
                   { name: Projekte[3][1], value: "val3" },
                   { name: Projekte[4][1], value: "val4" },
                   { name: Projekte[5][1], value: "val5" },
                   { name: Projekte[6][1], value: "val6" },
                   { name: Projekte[7][1], value: "val7" },
                   { name: Projekte[8][1], value: "val8" },
                   { name: Projekte[9][1], value: "val9" },
                   { name: Projekte[10][1], value: "val10" }
              ];
```

it looks like ther will be up to 100 Projects when the code is in charge, so how can I set name and value of this Object to the right length?

what i tried before was this:

```
var anzahlproj =100; //how many project i get
var myOptions = [
     { name: Projekte[1][1], value: "val1" }
 ];

 for(var i=2;i<anzahlproj + 1; i++){
     myOptions[name] +="Projekte["+i+"][1]",
     myOptions[value] += "val"+i;
 }
```

add something to a normal Object is no problem, but how can I add something with multiple elements?

I use: JQuery 1.11.1, JQuery Mobile 1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myOptions = [], i;

for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  myOptions.push({name: Projekte[i][1], value: "val" + i});
}
```

Comment: @NikiErnst: A few things to consider here, though: this code will only work if `Projekte` is an array with _at least_ 101 values, and it will always skip the first value (arrays are, as I explained in my answer) zero-indexed. `var anArray = [1,2,3]; console.log(anArray[0]);` will log `1`. use my last suggested snippet if this is an issue

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I set `i<Projekte.length` it works as it should, and my Projekte[0] is empty, thats no problem...anyway, thank you too for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var anzahlproj = 100; //how many project i get
for (var i = 2; i < anzahlproj + 1; i++) {
      var myOption = new Option(Projekte[i][1], "val" + i.toString());
      myOptions.append($(myOption));
}
```

Comment: Where's the `Option` constructor? Also: _"try this..."_. Some explanation wouldn't hurt, and a final nit-pik: `i.toString()` in a concatenation expression is redundant. If you want to convert to a string explicitly: `('' + i)` is shorter, too

Comment: option is the child element of DropDown list box (select control in HTML). Here myOptions is a DropDown list box.

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question/code that suggests the `myOptions` array is to be added to the DOM directly. he mentions a DropDown list, so I understand your assumption (the data being option nodes), but it still is just that: an assumption